# Grails: ArrayList - Retrieval Speed

Tags: grails, arraylist, findall, collect

I'm working on speed issues with a currently **working** method that finds a specific attribute collection within an `ArrayList`. Depending on the size, it can take longer than 7 seconds to find the value in the list.

I need to speed up this process, so I can deal with larger volumes of data. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Here is my example;

Method:

```
public ArrayList getIntegrationTag(String attribute) {
  return crmMapping?.findAll { it.get("ATTRIBUTE") == attribute }?.collect{
    it.INTEGRATION_TAG 
  }?.unique()
}//end getIntegrationTag(String attribute)
```

*crmMapping content*

> "[{ATTRIBUTE=AcademicIndex, INTEGRATION_TAG=Contact~nAcademic_Index},
>   {ATTRIBUTE=AcademicInterest,
>   INTEGRATION_TAG=Contact~msplAcademic_Interest},........]"

Comment: Why does the collection need to be that big? Assuming `crmMapping` is very big.

Comment: It is relatively large (well over 10,000 characters). It contains all of the field mapping information to import data into our Oracle CRM system using web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the findAll loops over each record, then the collect loops over each record, then unique loops over each record again.

Try...

```
Set result = [] as Set

for(element in crmMapping) {
  if(element.get("ATTRIBUTE") == attribute) {
    result << element.INTEGRATION_TAG
  }
}

return (result as ArrayList)
```

This will only loop once it it will be unique as it was added to a Set

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't want to offend anyone but not responding until Monday; evidently there is an issue with my VPN access. I really appreciate the help and I will try both your and @crudolf's answers on Monday;

Comment: This solution takes ~1/5 of the time versus the original code and it was simple to implement. The additional information about the # of loops was very insightful and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following once

```
def crmMappingMap = crmMapping.groupBy({ it.ATTRIBUTE })
```

Then you have a map of all same attribute instances and can access it using `crmMappingMap[attribute].INTEGRATION_TAG`, which will return the desired array, like this:

```
public ArrayList getIntegrationTag(String attribute) {
    crmMappingMap[attribute].INTEGRATION_TAG.unique()
}
```

Always keep a map, then speed of access will be fast enough.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I didn't want to offend anyone but not responding until Monday; evidently there is an issue with my VPN access. I really appreciate the help and I will try both your and @crudolf's answers on Monday;

Comment: Thank you again for the response. Your method works well and also saves time over the original code. I tried to up your reputation, but I don't have 15 rep points yet, so I'll come back at a later time and add to it.